# Can polyline shapefile hold geometries with 0 vertices?

Tags: shapefile, vertices, null-geometry

I have a polyline shapefile and a few geometries (5 out of 2000+) have no vertices at all.

I am a bit surprised and was wondering whether my shapefile is broken (so I have a bug when creating the shapefile) or my shapefile reader is broken (and does not consider for shapes with no vertices)?

I am actually reading the shapefile through a Python library (shapelib) trying to extract some information.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Hi PolyGeo,

I am actually reading the shapefile through a python library (shapelib) trying to extract some information.

Thank you for pointing out the 'Tour' and for the warm welcoming message.

I am actually not brand new: I had an account that I did not use for some time and could not remember my credentials to log in.

Comment: If you want to try and merge your accounts these instructions may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null shapes are valid in shapefiles. The specification:

http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

mentions it at the bottom of page 5.

You haven't said how you are reading these, but in R using the `sf` package they appear as "EMPTY" features:

```
  id                       geometry
1  1 POLYGON ((-1.47599164926931...
2  2                  POLYGON EMPTY
```

Comment: As are invalid ones, with self-intersections. The are numerous other horrors,  such as not being able to mix geometry types, but, at least, it is a standard of sorts.

Comment: Thank you spaced man! I was missing the concept of NULL geometries.

I am reading the shapes using the python library shapelib and I was seeing 0 vertices which I thought to be a broken geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be geometries with no vertices.
E.g. in QGIS you just click **Add feature** in a Table view and you have one. See quick example below, features 1, 2, 3, 5 have vertices; 4 and 6 do not.
[image]

E.g. in ArcGIS it is very easy to add a new record (just by typing in a new line of the table). Thus, many times empty geometries might be mistakes.